# How do I get this running properly?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to complete this code for my class and I just can't get this part to work.

I need the three input numbers to be compared with the three random numbers, when I run the code, after I put the inputs in, the only thing that prints out is the else statement even if some of the numbers matched.

```
for(int x=0; x<=array.length - 1; x++) {
    if(array[0] == Rand[0] && array[1] == Rand[1] && array[2] == Rand[2]) {
        System.out.println("Your guesses are: " + array[0] + " " + array[1] + " " + array[2]);
        System.out.println("Lucky numbers are: " + Rand1 + " " + Rand2 + " " + Rand3);
        System.out.println("You won $1000!");
        break;
    } else if(array[x] == Rand[0] && array[x] == Rand[1] && array[x] == Rand[2]) {
        System.out.println("Your guesses are: " + array[0] + " " + array[1] + " " + array[2]);
        System.out.println("Lucky numbers are: " + Rand1 + " " + Rand2 + " " + Rand3);
        System.out.println("You won $100");
        break;
    } else if(array[x] == Rand[0] && array[x] == Rand[1] ||
        array[x] == Rand[1] && array[x] == Rand[2] ||
        array[x] == Rand[0] && array[x] == Rand[2]) {
        System.out.println("Your guesses are: " + array[0] + " " + array[1] + " " + array[2]);
        System.out.println("Lucky numbers are: " + Rand1 + " " + Rand2 + " " + Rand3);
        System.out.println("You won $30!");
        break;
    } else if(array[x] == Rand[0] || array[x] == Rand[1] || array[x] == Rand[2]) {
        System.out.println("Your guesses are: " + array[0] + " " + array[1] + " " + array[2]);
        System.out.println("Lucky numbers are: " + Rand1 + " " + Rand2 + " " + Rand3);
        System.out.println("You won $5");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your guesses are: " + array[0] + " " + array[1] + " " + array[2]);
        System.out.println("Lucky numbers are: " + Rand1 + " " + Rand2 + " " + Rand3);
        System.out.println("You won nothing");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you debug your code?

Comment: Please show the types of `Rand` and `array`

Comment: Yes, and it worked for one run and then stopped working again @Stultuske

Comment: Unrelated, but the first two `System.out.println`s in each `if` can be safely moved out of the `if/else` chain

Comment: Where should I put them? @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: Just after the `for`

Comment: Also why are you iterating over the `array`? But then `break`ing always out of it?

Comment: Is it intentional to leave out the `break;` in one the `else if`?

Comment: Have a look at your conditions and think hard about what they mean. As an example `array[x] == Rand[0] && array[x] == Rand[1] && array[x] == Rand[2]` would mean that the value at index `x` would have to match 3 potentially random numbers - that's very unlikely to ever happen (depends on how you generate those random numbers though, but in most cases taking 3 random numbers will produce 3 _different_ numbers).

Comment: what is the size of your `Rand` array and what exactly is the condition to give a reward?

Comment: fixed that part, Thank you @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: Also note that you have that condition inside the loop so let's say you have 3 guesses then if _one_ of those guesses doesn't match (the one at index `x`) then you print the user lost, even if the other two might match - and since you always break the loop you only ever check the first number. Question: did you learn about sets already?

Comment: The size of both array and Rand are 3 @Thomas

Comment: The input is supposed to be 3 numbers between 10 and 19 and they are to be compared with the 3 random numbers.

Comment: if you get 1 match($5) 2 matches(30) 3 *out of order* ($100) and 3 *in exact order* ($1000)

Comment: is there a difference between Rand[0] and Rand1?

Comment: @mahieus No, they are the same

Comment: @JasonMeeks this should give you an idea: https://ideone.com/WHzJjo

Comment: The code is simple and it itches to post it but I agree with Thomas you should actually try to write it yourself based on his answer if you really want to learn something

Answer (score 1):

> if you get 1 match($5) 2 matches(30) 3 out of order ($100) and 3 in exact order ($1000)

So let's say `array` and `rand` have the same length and all numbers in `rand` are different (so no `1, 1, 5` or so).

Then you'd check the following:

1. For each index check the element in `array` and `rand` at that index. If all match you are done, the user guessed 3 in order.
2. If not all match then you check each element in `array` against each element in `rand` and count the number of matches. That number then tells you whether the user won 0, 5, 30 or 100 bucks.

Note that I deliberately didn't post any code because that code is "for your class" and thus it is *your* task to actually write the code and learn something from doing so.

**Edit**

In your comment you state that the 3 random numbers could be all the same. That would require you to go about it a little differently. One approach might be to have a temporary copy of `rand` and when you found a match you "remove" the element from that copy (e.g. if `rand` is an `int[]` array you could set the matching element to `-1` and when comparing the elements of `array` with those of `rand` you ignore any that have the value -1).

Using lists might be easier (i.e. you actually remove any matches) but I assume you didn't learn about those yet.

Comment: 1,1,5 would be allowed. No restrictions on the random numbers. They could all be 11 if it happened

Comment: does the position also need to match? say 1, 1, 5 and I guessed 1, 5, 9. Would that give me 5 or 30 bucks?

Comment: @mahieus that should give you 30, because of the 1 and the 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach of counting how many numbers are matching in both the ArrayLists
(The work is incomplete you can finish it off):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    Random rn = new Random();
    int max=1000;
    int min=10;

    ArrayList<Integer>random=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        random.add(rn.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min);
        System.out.println(random.get(i));
    }

    ArrayList<Integer>array=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        array.add(input.nextInt());
    }

    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            if (random.get(i).equals(array.get(j)))
                count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);

}
```

In this approach, I am taking in 3 inputs in `array` and generating 3 random numbers in `random` between 10 and 1000(you can change this of course by changing `min` and `max`)
After checking how many entries match, and counting them in `count`, you can use that count in your `if-else` structure to give the prizes. for example `if(count==2) give $100` or whatever. You can add checks in so that the Random numbers are unique and so that the count value is accurate.

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> Random` - I strongly recommend _not_ using uppercase names for variables as stated by the Java code conventions. How would you as a programmer know what `Random.whatever()` refers to (by just looking at the code without the help of an IDE) - the list `Random` or the class `Random` which you are using as well?

Comment: I agree @Thomas, I just used that because the original question had that variable used.

Comment: Thank you! ill try this out!

Comment: Well, the original question used `Rand` not `Random` :)

Comment: happy now? @Thomas

Comment: this doesn't take the orde into consideration and also in case there the random numbers are 1, 1, 5 and you guess 5, 1, 9 you would get three matches

Comment: One note on your code: assume `random` contains the same number 3 times (as per the OP's comment to my question that would be allowed to happen). Now the user guesses 1,2,3 and let's say the random list contains 1,1,1 - the user would get $100 because 1 is contained 3 times in the random list (even though he just guessed 1 number correctly).

Comment: @Thomas I have already said at the end of my answer that you can add checks so that unique `Random` values are added in the ArrayList `random` and no values are repeated

Comment: Yes you _could_ add checks but I'll cite the OP: "1,1,5 would be allowed. No restrictions on the random numbers. They could all be 11 if it happened" - so no checks/restrictions are needed/allowed.

Comment: That really should have been mentioned in the problem statement then.. @Thomas

Comment: You're right, but actually he didn't state anything so I stated that as an assumption and got that info as a comment. - We could have asked though ;)